# Using wget for adminer but is something wrong?

Tags: wget

I'm new to Linux and recently I've been thinking to use adminer with my sql so I used the command

```bash
wget https://www.adminer.org/latest-mysql-en.php
```

And I got this output:

```
https://www.adminer.org/latest-mysql-en.php
Resolving www.adminer.org (www.adminer.org)... 
Connecting to www.adminer.org (www.adminer.org)... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: static/download/4.8.1/adminer-4.8.1-mysql-en.php [following]
----  https://www.adminer.org/static/download/4.8.1/adminer-4.8.1-mysql-en.php
Reusing existing connection to www.adminer.org:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 212634 (208K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘latest-mysql-en.php’
latest-mysql-en.php 100%[================>] 207,65K   730KB/s    in 0,3s    
‘latest-mysql-en.php’ saved [212634/212634]
```

**Questions:**

What it seems wrong there? Where was latest-mysql-en.php saved? Can I remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is saved in the directory where you ran `wget`.
In case you did not change the directory after opening the terminal it is probably saved in your home folder at `/home/<USERNAME>/latest-mysql-en.php` (or use the shortcut `~/latest-mysql-en.php`). You can then run `ls` to list all files and subdirectories in the current directory.
You can delete a file using `rm <PATH>`.

Comment: thanks for your explanation and your instant response :)